# Main menu disappears after updating Summary Fields extension under wordpress

Tags: wordpress, extension, summaryfields

I use latest civi 5.10.0 in Wordpress 5.0.3. Today I was warned to update Summary Fields to 4.0.0 version. After update the main menu disappeared from my civi installation. The Cleanup Caches and Update paths did not help.

Finally I can disable the extension, the menu appeared again and works correctly.

Comment: There is an issue filed under github for this https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/issues/44.  Also, I know it isn't limited to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer released 4.0.2 which fixes the issue.  It sounds like their test env possibly isn't getting all the caches or something flushed.

Comment: Paul - thanks for helping by updating this issue. perhaps you could edit your previous Answers rather than adding new ones. helps reduce reading folk have to do to get to the 'latest' answer

Answer (score 3):

The developer updated the issue.  There is a missing line in the code.  They say they will release version 4.0.1 overnight.  If you want to fix it yourself before that look at issue linked above in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the fix in 4.0.1 didn't fix the issue.  See [Navigation Menu Lost](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28428/navigation-menu-lost) for more details.